# Regex match word groups and parts of previously matched word groups

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match groups of words from a piece of text. Basically I want every single word with 4 or more characters, every group of 2 words where the first word is 4 or more and the second word is 3 or more characters and every group of 3 words with the first word with 4 or more characters and the second and third with 3 or more characters.

My problem here is that my attempts of creating a regex for this only return matches one time only for a given part of the text where I would like to get all matches.

In example, when I have this text:
"This is an example text to explain the problem I am having with the regular expression"

It should return an array with the following values:

```
This
example
text
explain
problem
having
with
regular
expression
example text
explain the
having with
with the
regular expression
explain the problem
having with the
with the regular
```

I've tried both single and seperate regexes, but the problem remains that it would only matches a part of the string one time. In example if I try the following regex:

```
/\b(\w{4,}\s\w{3,}\s\w{3,})\b/
```

It should match

```
having with the
with the regular
```

I've also tried

```
/\b(?<triple>(?<double>(?<single>\w{4,})(\s\w{3,})?)(\s\w{3,})?)\b/
```

Which also only matches

```
This
example
explain
having
regular
example text
explain the
having with
regular expression
explain the problem
having with the
```

Anyone with a better idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you want to catch overlapping patterns (like "having with" and "with the"). You can do this with a cunning bit of look-ahead. I haven't managed to combine into a single regex with this method yet, but you could do something like this:

```
$text = 'This is an example text to explain the problem I am having with the regular expression';

preg_match_all('/\b(\w{4,})\b/', $text, $matches1);
preg_match_all('/\b(?=(\w{4,}\s+\w{3,}))\b/', $text, $matches2);
preg_match_all('/\b(?=(\w{4,}\s+\w{3,}\s+\w{3,}))\b/', $text, $matches3);

var_dump(array_merge($matches1[1], $matches2[1], $matches3[1]));
```

Comment: No worries! I *have* managed to get it into a single regex, but it's horrible: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Sbm2lg

Comment: Thanks again for the effort, but I think I'll stick with the 3 seperate preg calls.

Comment: I hoped you would, it was more of an exercise for myself really :-)

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds interesting. I don't know [php](/questions/tagged/php) but I decided to challenge myself to resolve it with [python](/questions/tagged/python), that I'm more used to it.

```
import regex

s = r"This is an example text to explain the problem I am having with the regular expression"
[elem for t in 
    regex.findall(r'\m(?|(((\w{4,})\W+\w{3,})\W+\w{3,})|((\w{4,})\W+\w{3,})|(\w{4,}))', s, overlapped=True) 
        for elem in t if elem != '']
```

I've used the `regex` module and its `overlapped` option that begins next match from the character following the current one. The regular expression returns tuples like:

```
[('This', '', ''),
 ('example text', 'example', ''),
 ('text', '', ''),
 ('explain the problem', 'explain the', 'explain'),
 ('problem', '', ''),
 ('having with the', 'having with', 'having'),
 ('with the regular', 'with the', 'with'),
 ('regular expression', 'regular', ''),
 ('expression', '', '')]
```

So from there I do another loop to extract those fields that are not blank, that yields:

```
['This',
 'example text',
 'example',
 'text',
 'explain the problem',
 'explain the',
 'explain',
 'problem',
 'having with the',
 'having with',
 'having',
 'with the regular',
 'with the',
 'with',
 'regular expression',
 'regular',
 'expression']
```

Comment: Your implementation is missing the overlapping matches. Compare your result set with the result set in the first post. I Like the clean implementation in Python though.

Comment: @riekelt: You are right. I will try harder. Otherwise I will have to delete it.

Comment: @riekelt: I've fixed it using another approach.